# Swift: changing value inside class structured array

Tags: swift, oop, generics, nsmutablearray

```
class Store: NSObject {

var storeNumber : NSString!
var storetitle : NSString!

init(number:NSString, stTitle title : NSString) {
        self.storeNumber = number
        self.storetitle = title
    }
}
```

`var arrStore : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()`

```
var store = Store(number: "1", stTitle: "Adidas")
self.arrStore.addObject(store)

var store = Store(number: "2", stTitle: "Nike")
self.arrStore.addObject(store)
```

I want to change the value of the title "Nike"? How could I do that?

The below code changes the title of all objects in arrStore array:

```
self.arrStore.setValue("rebook", forKey: "storetitle")
```

I want something like:

```
self.arrStore.setValue("rebook", forKey: "storetitle")[1]
```

But unfortunately it is wrong!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```swift
let store = arrStore.objectAtIndex(1) as Store

store.storetitle = "New title"
```

or the more concise syntax:

```swift
let store = arrStore[1] as Store

store.storetitle = "New title"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Swift array rather than NSMutableArray.

```
var array = [Store]()


var store = Store(number: "1", stTitle: "Adidas")
self.arrStore.append(store)

var store = Store(number: "2", stTitle: "Nike")
self.arrStore.append(store)


array[0].storetitle = "New Title"
```